# How can a remove space between input field HTML

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a form like this:

[image]

And this is what I get:

[image]

This is my HTML

```html
<input class="form-field" style="background-color: #d7d7d7; color: #62534e; font-family: Verdana; font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px;" name="firstname" type="text" value="Nombre" />
<input class="form-field" style="background-color: #d7d7d7; color: #62534e; font-family: Verdana; font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px;" name="firstname" type="text" value="Teléfono" />
<input class="form-field" style="background-color: #d7d7d7; color: #62534e; font-family: Verdana; font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px;" name="firstname" type="text" value="E-Mail" />

<select style="background-color: #d7d7d7; color: #62534e; font-family: Verdana; font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px;">
<option value="pro">Programa de interés</option>
<option value="Pro">Programa 1</option>
<option value="pro">Programa 2</option>
<option value="pro">Programa 3</option>
</select>
<input name="option1" type="checkbox" value="1" /> Text here
```

Comment: Add your CSS too in the question

Comment: I dont know how to do it with CSS thats why i am asking for help i just know HTML

Comment: I am here to help you. just up your code in http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: You have a lot of CSS on your code... At least you know how to copy and paste it..

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your Html code inside head tag

```
 <style>
    form{
    padding:5px;

    }
    input{
    margin:3px;
    }
    </style>
```